# Shell script to manipulate if loop

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I am trying to modify a if loop in a large code base.My need is as follows.

The code may contain as follows.This is just a random combination example of an if condition.I need to modify if else if conditions alone.

```
if((A==B)&&(C==D)&&((E==F)||(G==H))||(I)&&(J!=K))
```

should be modified as

```
 if((string.Compare(A,B)==0)&&(string.Compare(C,D)==0)&&((string.Compare(E,F)==0)||(string.Compare(G,H)==0))||(I)&&(string.Compare(J,K)!=0))
```

I tried with Java but utterly failed.I believe this is possible with sed or awk.Any help?

Comment: ANTLR is kind of perfect for that purpose :)

Comment: can't use ANTLR.Need shell or java or c#

Comment: -1 The question is really unclear. You should put some effort if you want to be understood. Don't just blame others.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear.I will upvote your answer so that it does not affect your reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it basically with any language that supports regular expressions replacement.

Here's a 3 lines working **C#** example:

```
string text = "if((A==B)&&(C==D)&&((E==F)||(G==H))||(I)&&(J!=K))";
string pattern = @"\((?:(\w)((?:=|!)=)(\w))\)";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => string.Format("(string.Compare({0},{1}){2}0)", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[3].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));

Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

And the result:

> `if((string.Compare(A,B)==0)&&(string.Compare(C,D)==0)&&((string.Compare(E,F)==0)||(string.Compare(G,H)==0))||(I)&&(string.Compare(J,K)!=0))`

Comment: I guess this is what I want.I will try to get the equivalent of it in Java as I am not well versed with c#

Comment: @Harish Try doing it with Java. See how Java replaces regex matches, and then translate the code. The regular expression should be the same.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -r 's/([[:alpha:]])([=!]=)([[:alpha:]])/string.Compare(\1,\3) \2 0/g'
```

The spaces around `\2` aren't strictly necessary.

Comment: Very interesting :) What does the `0/g` at the end means?

Comment: @Oscar, "0" is just a zero, for the `string.Compare` boolean value. "/" marks the end of the replacement text for sed's `s` command. "g" means perform the search and replace globally in the text.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to use `awk` or `sed` to construct the `if` statement. It is enough to write:

```
if [ A == B -a C == D -a ( E == F -o G == H ) -o I -a J != K ]; then
    your code here
fi
```

The `==` operator compares strings. If you wanted to compare numbers use `-eq` operator. See [this chapter of `bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) (scroll down to `test` command), and the [description of usage of primary conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

Comment: I'm almost sure that he's not talking about it. What he wants is to convert some code file syntax to another.

Comment: actually you got my question wrong.Its about manipulating the text inside if loop not about if loop